# Converting decimal to binary in java. This code works perfect till n=1023 but after this it gives wrong answer

Tags: java, binary

It doesn't work for 1024 and above

```
while (n != 0 ){
    rem = n%2;
    n = n/2;
    bin = bin + rem * i ;
    i*=10;
}
```

Comment: What exactly this code is supposed to do? (oh, I see, it builds decimal number that looks like binary). Well, then the reason is that 1024 occupies 10 digits in binary, while `int` can hold only 9.

Comment: `int` is limited to `2^31-1`, so `10000000000` is too large.

Comment: An `int` is already a 32-bit binary. The only reason it prints as decimal as Java does this by default. What you are doing is making it print binary when it tries to print it as decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `int` (and any primitive numeric types) have a maximal value, your approach is bound to fail when the binary representation of your input number exceeds the max value that can be stored in `bin`. Hence you fail for 1024, since `10000000000` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

To avoid this problem, you can use a `String` variable to hold the binary representation :

```
String bin = "";
while (n != 0) {
    rem = n%2;
    n = n/2;
    bin = rem + bin;
}
```